# google analytics: what is the difference between referrer path vs previous page path?

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to find out the difference in Google analytics between "Referral path" and "Previous page path"?

The task is to get a number of visits that came to a page from another section of the web site. The section contains many pages which I want to regard as a sole referrer.

I made the following experiment:

- 1) setup an Advanced segment with two conditions page title contains
  "x page title" AND referral path contains "y-product".
- 2) compared
  the figures from (1) with the sum of numbers under "Previous Page
  Path" in "Navigation summary".

In short, there is nothing in common between both numbers. So, what are the "referrer" and "previous page" in Google Analytics? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "referrer" is the external referring URL of the first page a visitor lands on in the visit.  For example, if a visitor performs a google search and your site comes up and they click on the link and go to your site, the referrer would be google.com (assuming your site is not google.com!).  If the visitor then clicks on some random link on your site and goes to another page on your site, the referrer is still google.com.

The "Previous Page" is the page the visitor was previously on for a given page.  This will always change, each time a visitor goes to a new page on your site.

**Example**

```
google.com > 
yoursite.com/page1.html 
/*referrer=google.com, prev page=(entrance)*/

google.com > 
yoursite.com/page1.html > 
yoursite.com/page2.html 
/*referrer=google.com, prev page=page1.html*/

google.com > 
yoursite.com/page1.html > 
yoursite.com/page2.html >
yoursite.com/page3.html
/*referrer=google.com, prev page=page2.html*/
```